# I cant find what is creating the space at the bottom of my website

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I am really struggling to find what is making the grey space at the bottom of my site. This is the first time I have attempted any coding so any simply put answers would be greatly appreciated. I am sure there are numerous errors in the code / conflicting codes but 
I have also been trying media queries which may also be making stuff go wrong? Any help would be really well received... Here is the code so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Your Website</title>

<style>


a:link {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "georgia";
font-style: normal;
font-size: 20px;
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "georgia";
font-style: normal;
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
font-style: normal;
font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #c57b43; 
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
font-style: normal;
font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
}

* {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: -5px;


}

#footer { 

    position: fixed; 
    clear: both; 
    width: 104%; 
    height: 30px; 
    bottom: 0; 
    border: none; 
    padding: 13px 0 0 0; 
    text-align: 
    center; color: #ffffff; 
    background-color: #ffffff; }


body {
    background-color:grey;
    height: auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%\9


    }











}

#container {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        color:blue;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0; 
        position: absolute;


    }
        #nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
        font-size: 20px;
        word-spacing: 20px;
        float:left;

}   



navtype { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 60px; 
        left: 0; 
        width: 100%;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
        font-size: 20px;
        word-spacing: 20px;

}

#images { 
        position: relative;
        width:100%; /* you can use % */
        height: auto;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
        font-size: 20px;
        top: 0px;
}






        #fullscreen  {
        position: relative;
        width:100%; /* you can use % */
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        min-width: 50%;
        text-align: center;


        }



        #test  {
        position: absolute;
        width:100%; /* you can use % */
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        min-width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: block;


        }








    #ourstory {
        position: relative;
        width:100%; /* you can use % */
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        min-width: 50%;

        text-align: center;


        background-image: url("/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW 
  SCROLL DOWNSITE/images/storyback.jpg" );
        background-size: 100%;



}

#type { 
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: 70%;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #5f4029; 
        line-height: 180%;
        font-size: 15px;


}



@media all and (min-width: 601px) {
#test {background-image:url("/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW 
SCROLL DOWN SITE/images/breaker.jpg" );
width:100%;height:100%;


}
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
#test {background-image:url("/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW 
SCROLL DOWN SITE/images/breakermobile.jpg" );width:100%;height:100%;



}


    #type {

    position: relative;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: 70%;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #5f4029; 
        line-height: 180%;
        font-size: 10px;


}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "georgia";
font-style: normal;
font-size: 13px;
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "georgia";
font-style: normal;
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
font-style: normal;
font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #c57b43; 
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
font-style: normal;
font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
}

* {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
margin-top: -5px;


}

    #nav {
        width: 100%;

        text-align: center;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 0px;
        height: 60px;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
        font-size: 20px;
        word-spacing: 20px;
        position:relative;

    }   



    navtype { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 30px; 
        left: 0; 
        width: 100%;
        font-family: "georgia";
        font-weight:lighter;
        color: #7a5131; 
        font-size: 20px;
        word-spacing: 20px;
}









}




</style>    



</head>

<body>





<div id="container">

    <div id="nav">

    <navtype><span>
    <a href="#storyanchor"class="smoothScroll">Story</a> 
    <a href="#testimonial"class="smoothScroll">Testimonial</a>  
    <a href="#recipes"class="smoothScroll">Recipes</a> 
    <a href="#ourspreads"class="smoothScroll">Spreads</a>             
    </span></navtype>

    <a name="top"></a>

    <img src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/            images/headerbar.jpg" 
    alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </div>



    <div id="images">

    <img src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/            images/landscape.jpg" 
    alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:100%;height:100%">

    </div>





    <div id="ourstory">

    <a name="storyanchor"></a> 

    <div id="images">

    <img src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/            images/storypics.png" 
    alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:100%;height:100%">

    </div>



    <div id="type">

    How it all began
    <br>

    The emergence and growth of blogs in the late 1990s coincided           with the advent o
    web publishing tools that facilitated the           posting of &nbsp;content by non tec

 (Previously, &nbsp;a knowledge &nbsp;of &nbsp;such technologies    as HTML and  FTpu                                             Indeed, bloggers do not only produce content to post on theirblogs, but also build social relations
    <br><br>
    <a href="#storyanchor">Click Here For More Recipe ideas </a>
    </div>



</div>



            <a name="testimonial"></a>
        <img src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/images/breaker.jpg" 
    alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:100%;height:100%">








</div>




    <div id="ourstory">

    <a name="ourspreads"></a> 

    <div id="images">

    <img src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/            images/jars.png" 
    alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:100%;height:100%">

    </div>



    <div id="type">

    Our Spreads and Jams
    <br>

    The emergence and growth of blogs in the late 1990s coincided           with the advent of `      web publishing tools that facilitated the             posting of &nbsp;content by &nbsp;non-technical users. &nbsp;           (Previously, &nbsp;a knowledge &nbsp;of &nbsp;such technologies         as HTML and FTP had been required to publish ;content on the            Web.)Indeed, bloggers do not only produce content to post on their      blogs, but also build social relations

    </div>


        <div id="fullscreen">


        <a name="recipes"></a>      
    <div id="images">

    <img src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/            images/recipes.jpg" 
    alt="HTML5 Icon"style="width:100%;height:100%">

    </div>



    </div>


    <div id="test">


    </div>

</div>


<div id="footer">
<a href="#top"class="smoothScroll">Back to top</a></p>

</div> <!--END OFCONTAINER browser-->

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/DESIGNHAPPY04/Desktop/NEW SCROLL DOWN SITE/java/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please make a code snippet

Comment: It appears like you didn't close your `<div>` with the id "ourstory"

Comment: You should run your HTML the the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/  There are a number of good suggestions it will give you to correct your code, and possibly fix your problem in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys Im gonna look into all the tips and see if I have any joy... gotta love the internet, I already spent two whole evenings trying to figure out what I had done wrong...

Comment: when you say a code snippet how should I make this?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on coding your own site. Here are some things that could be causing the odd gap:

Two default CSS styles that will effect spacing

1. **Small space under an image**, and this may be your bug. One quick fix is to change the image to `display:block;`. Another solution is to use `vertical-align: bottom;`, as demonstrated in this easy article: http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/10/remove-space-below-images-and-inline-block-elements.html
2. **Margin Collapse** happens when a top or bottom margin from one html element (divs, headings...) touch another without a border, padding or anything else in-between. One margin is deleted or the margins are added together, and will only be applied to one element. Please see this article for more info: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/

Potential problems within your code:

3. As Sable Foste suggested, run your code through the validator, and concentrate on the code errors. (You may not be able to fix everything the validator suggests.) Remember to fix the errors mentioned in the comments above, along with fixing the missing opening `<p>` tag in the footer, and removing the extra closing brackets `}` in the css under the body and navtype. Add the additional media query closing brackets `}` (they need 2: one for the actual style and one to close the media query). Remember to fix `* {padding: 0px; margin:0px; margin-top:-5px;}` by removing the margin-top:-5px, and assign this only to the styles that need a -5px top margin. These may seem trivial, but coding errors can wreak havoc on your layout.
4. It looks like your using `<div id="test">` at the bottom to test the media queries. What you can do is use `#test {display:none;}` to hide the div in the regular css, and turn it back on by adding `#test {display:block;}` in the media queries. This may help you see if the test div is causing problems.

---

You asked about using a code snippet. Since this is an entire web page, perhaps a JSFiddle would be helpful.

[**JSFiddle Tutorial**](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html) - this site lets you paste your html, css, and scripts in a separate, editable environment. It then displays the results in a small browser window. You can paste the link, and we can troubleshoot and demonstrate the fixes in a real environment. For example, the code you supplied does not show your problem, but if you had it in a JSFiddle, we could see the issue, help troubleshoot it, and offer a real example solution. If you have a JSFiddle example, people are more willing to help.

---

Useful Info

**Developer Tools** - learn how to use the built in developer tools in your browser because it'll be your best friend when troubleshooting your site. (Like the rest of us, this won't be your last bug). You can view your html and css code, and it has the added benefit of being able to turn off and even delete html elements and css styles. This helps to quickly find the offending element. It is safe to make edits in this environment because the changes are in the browser, and will not change your real code. Hit F12 in your browser to open developer tools, then use the little arrow and mouse over your elements in the browser window, and the code that displays below. Right click on the element to see more options. You can use Firefox with the downloadable [Firebug extensions](http://getfirebug.com/). This lets you edit the html and css. Lots of people like Chrome's developer tools, and you are in luck because [CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools) offers a fun, free and easy course. It'll be well worth your time to take this because in the time it takes you to troubleshoot one bug, you could have finished this course.

When using this site, upvote the comments and answers that are helpful, and accept the answer that solves your problem. Upvoting and accepting builds your reputation and shows you are an active participant with your own questions, it builds the reputation of the people that answer your questions, and it builds the reputation of the question. If you find your own solution, it's helpful to post the fix.

Comment: Sorry havent looked at this post for a while thanks to everyone who helped... really couldn't learn this without